# Client side data annotation validation is not working on partial views using firefox and chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

i have the following Main view inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <th>
        Lab Test
        </th>
        <th>
        Result
        </th>
        <th>
        Date Taken
        </th>
        <th>
        Comment
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
 @for (int item = 0; item < 10; item++)
        {
using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAll", "VisitLabResult", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    UpdateTargetId = item.ToString(),
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = string.Format(
                   "disableform({0})",
                   Json.Encode(item)),
}))
{ <tr id = "@item">
        @Html.Partial("_create",Model)
       </tr>
            }
        } </table>
```

**which renders the following _create partial view:-**
@section scripts{

}

```
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("LabTestID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LabTestID)
   </td>
   <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Result)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Result)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTaken)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTaken)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment)

    </td>
    <td>
    <input type= "hidden" name = "visitid" value = "@ViewBag.visitid" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </td>
```

currently all the data annotation client side validation such as Required will not show up whe using firefox or chrome but they will work correctly using IE9 ,, so what might be the problem.
BR

Answer (score 0):

I found a typo in this code block. You added a komma after you Json.Encode(item). If this is the last item, you cannot add a komma.

```
<table>
            <tr>
            <th>
            Lab Test
            </th>
            <th>
            Result
            </th>
            <th>
            Date Taken
            </th>
            <th>
            Comment
            </th>
            <th>

            </th>
     @for (int item = 0; item < 10; item++)
     {
         using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAll", "VisitLabResult", new AjaxOptions{
                HttpMethod = "Post",
                UpdateTargetId = item.ToString(),
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                OnSuccess = string.Format("disableform({0})", Json.Encode(item))})
         ){ 
             <tr id = "@item">
                 @Html.Partial("_create",Model)
             </tr>
         }
     } 
</table>
```

Hope this will work. Let me know.